# MOSFET gate area?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, vlsi

I have a transistor with constant Vdd voltage but my W, L parameters are decreasing - what happens to my gate area?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you shows us your schematic, what transistor/mosfet you use and how did you find out your W, L parameters are decreasing? Shows us your measurements so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the anwser of Mr. Abdelhalim abdelnaby Zekry in this post (https://www.researchgate.net/post/is_w_l_ratio_of_mosfet_can_effect_the_efficiency_of_the_circuit) about a similar question:

> Dear Wafa, The W/L ratio is the major parameter in the hand of the
> engineer to adjust the current in its transistor.
>
> This can be easily understood from the current equation of the MOS
> transistor in the saturation mode of operation:
>
> ID= (Kp W/2L) (VGS- Vtn)^2
>
> where Kp is transconductance parameter and Vtn is the threshold
> voltage. The other symbols have their usual meaning.
>
> VGS is normally limited by the power supply voltage for a given
> feature size.
>
> So it remains to increase W/L to increase the transistor current.
> Increasing the transistor current keeping its VDS constant increases
> the power consumption in the transistor.
>
> One normally choose L minimum to reduce the area required to achieve
> certain current and increase W as required.
>
> Decreasing the area is also required for to reduce the MOS capacitor
> to achieve high switching speed or high operating frequency.
>
> For more information on the MOSFET please see the book in the link:
>
> https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236003006_Electronic_Devices

Comment: This answer needs a bit more contextualization and detail since it seems to make some underlying assumptions about the design goals and technology. I work in a deep.submicron process and I would never set minimum L, unless I really didn't care about output impedance and needed the fastest Ft possible. For many analog designs and specific transistors in those designs, minimizing L should not be the methodology applied.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, your gate area is W*L. In practice there will probably be some overlap with the drain and source due to manufacturing process limits. This will also affect the mosfet's gate capacitance and hence its bandwidth.

As previously stated, the W/L ratio controls the transconductance of the mosfet, as well as it's output resistance in simple models.
However, the individual dimensions are significant to the function of the transistor, not only their ratio. Small transistors will behave very differently than large transistor due to short channel effects. There are no simple equations for these, pracitcal short-channel models usually take dozens or hundreds of different parameters.